# How to make docker client communicate with more than one daemon

Tags: docker

I am a newbie to docker. When I go through docker tutorial, I saw that **"Docker client can communicate with more than one daemon**". What does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Docker daemon listens on a Unix socket, `/var/run/docker.sock`. However, Docker can also be configured to listen on a TCP socket. In fact, it is often configured this way on Mac and Windows systems because Docker is actually running inside a virtual machine and the default Docker socket is not available on the host filesystem.

Because there are different ways of connecting to Docker, you must be able to configure the Docker client to connect to a Docker daemon at a specific location. You can do this using the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.  You can point this at a network location:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
```

Or at an alternate socket location:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///tmp/docker.sock
```

If you have Docker configured to listen for tcp connections, you can use the Docker client on a single machine to communicate with Docker on multiple hosts (but if you decide to do something like this, read through "[Protect the Docker daemon socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/)").

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/docker-overview/#the-docker-client),

> The Docker client can communicate with more than one daemon.

This means that the command-line utility `docker` can connect to different services that run in the background,

> Docker uses a client-server architecture. The Docker client talks to the Docker daemon, which does the heavy lifting of building, running, and distributing your Docker containers.

So for example, you could [configure the daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon) to run on a separate machine and connect to it from your workstation.